# File name and extension lost during move -cmd

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, move

This little code moves folders into subfolders ( by the way I found this here on stackowerflow. thanks :) ). I added some other functions and it works nicely except one part. See below the code, the problematic part is the last part here.

I wanna search for .txt files in the folders and move them up right under the parent directory (this part is working). But unfortunately the files lost their extensions and also their name changes to the name of the parent dir. You can see it on the attached image (I copied not moved the file there):
[image]

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "ROOT_FOLDER=C:\Users\xy\Desktop\folder"

:: For each folder in root folder
cd "%ROOT_FOLDER%"
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   cd "%%a"

   :: Move all existent folders into "XY" folder
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ('dir /B /A:D') do (
      md XY 2> NUL
      move "%%b" "XY\%%b"
   )

   :: Move all existent files into "XY" folder
   md XY 2> NUL
   move *.* XY

   :: Move txt files under parent folder
   for /R "XY" %%m in (*.txt) do move "\\?\%%m" "%%a"

   cd ..
)
pause
```

Can you help what I'm messing up here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, meanwhile I figured it finally.
The `%%a` was the problem. The program needs the full path to move the file correctly:

```
for /R "XY" %%m in (*.txt) do move "\\?\%%m" "%ROOT_FOLDER%\%%a"
```